# yii include of indirect libraries

Tags: php, yii, couchdb

Hi people i have a problem!
I need to include phpillow (http://arbitracker.org/phpillow) in Yii.
I do that:
in config/main.php

```
    'components'=>array(
            'RunDB'=>array(
                'class' => 'RunDB',
                    //'host'=>'localhost',
                    //'port'=>'5984',
                     //username
                     //password
            ),
```

in components/RunDB.php

```
class RunDB extends CComponent {

function init(){
    Yii::import('application.vendors.couchDB.*');
    require 'environment.php';
    phpillowConnection::createInstance('localhost',5984);
}
```

}

and i have error 500 when the line phpillowConnection not commented.
Without yii phpillow work well. How to force it to work with yii?!

---

output in the log:

```
[Sun Nov 27 22:42:18 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  include(arbitPhpErrorException.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/yii/yii/framework/YiiBase.php on line 396
[Sun Nov 27 22:42:18 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'arbitPhpErrorException.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/CouchTest/protected/vendors/couchDB/libraries/:.:/var/www/CouchTest/protected/vendors/couchDB:/var/www/CouchTest/protected/components:/var/www/CouchTest/protected/models:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/yii/yii/framework/YiiBase.php on line 396
[Sun Nov 27 22:42:18 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'arbitPhpErrorException' not found in /var/www/CouchTest/protected/vendors/couchDB/environment.php on line 160
```

Comment: Whats the error output? we need more information.

Comment: А где лежит файл arbitPhpErrorException.php?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your problem is that you haven't registered you library's autoloader, and therefore it cannot autoload the classes it needs.

read [this wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/165/understanding-autoloading-helper-classes-and-helper-functions) and take a look at [Yii::registerAutoloader](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/YiiBase/#registerAutoloader-detail)

If your library uses PEAR class notation then the [ZendAutoloader extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/zendautoloader) for yii might be what you need